# displaying products with categories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble with uri segments in codeigniter I am looking to develop products and product details so I created a controller for it and passed a parameter of product name to show product name in the url so my url will become like this

> localhost/project_name/products/product_name

and this part is working fine for me but I am confused about what If I would like to display as products category and product name like I am trying to make my url like this

> localhost/project_name/products/category_name /product_name

so how I will do this now when I pass in category name it shows me 404 not found The page you requested was not found. as some times direct product will be shown and sometimes if users go through the product details via category so the category name will passed in the url and also how this segements work ? I am having big confusion about this

Here is my controller for products

```
public function products($product_name) {
        if($this->uri->segment(3)) {
            $category = ucwords(str_replace('-', " ", $product_name));
            $product  = ucwords(str_replace('-', " ", $this->uri->segment(3)));
        } else {
            $product  = ucwords(str_replace('-', " ", $product_name));
        }

        $page_data = $this->get_data->get_Data($product, 'name', 'products');
        $data['title'] = 'Products - ' . $page_data->row()->name;
        $data['body_class'] = 'poductsdetails';

        $this->load->view('includes/header.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation.php');

        $data['content'] = array(
                'name'        => $page_data->row()->name,
                'price'       => $page_data->row()->price,
                'description' => $page_data->row()->description,
                'picture'     => $page_data->row()->picture,
                'category'    => $page_data->row()->category,
            );

        $this->load->view('products/details', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer-form.php');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer.php');
    }
```

And here is my routes I have created

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['admin']              = 'admin/index';
$route['admin/([a-z])']      = 'admin/$1';
$route['products/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1';
$route['products/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1/$2';
$route['products/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)']             = 'home/page/$1';
$route['(:any)']             = 'home/page/$1/$2';
```

Comment: It is not useful to pass category name to see individual product details

Comment: Well it is my client's requirement he is doing for seo purpose and I am stucked up here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just passed one parameter in route that's why it can't find

change your route like this

```
$route['products/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1';
$route['products/(:any)/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1/$2';
$route['products/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)']    = 'home/products/$1/$2/$3';
```

It will work.

Comment: Yes it worked thank you  can you explain me about (:any) as I know products will be the folder name so what (:any) refers to ?

Comment: (:any) This is a parameter which will pass in url as product or category like you add $1 or $2.

Comment: great thank you very much you have lot's of knowledge thank you

Comment: Welcome.I don't have lot's of knowledge i am also student as you :)

Comment: great learning like me I have 2 years 4 years of experience in wordpres and 2 years in php just started working on codeigniter hoping to learn a lot now

Answer (score 0):

if category_name is function defined in this controller then  try this

```
$route['products/category_name/(:any)'] = 'products/category_name/$1';
```